# StyleCop-Where's my output?

Tags: c#, stylecop

When I run it, I see this output in the "Output" window.

Where can I find the detail about the actual violations found?

```
------ StyleCop started ------

Pass 1: Form1.Designer.cs...
Pass 1: Form1.cs...
Pass 1: MonthPeriod.cs...
Pass 1: Application.Designer.cs...
Pass 1: MonthPeriods.cs...
Pass 1: AssemblyInfo.cs...
Pass 1: Resources.Designer.cs...
Pass 1: MyNamespaceSupportForCSharp.cs...
Loaded Analyzer: Documentation Rules...Loaded Analyzer: Layout Rules...Loaded Analyzer: Maintainability Rules...Loaded Analyzer: Naming Rules...Loaded Analyzer: Ordering Rules...Loaded Analyzer: Readability Rules...Loaded Analyzer: Spacing Rules...Pass 1: Period.cs...
Pass 2: Form1.cs...
Pass 2: Application.Designer.cs...
Pass 2: MyNamespaceSupportForCSharp.cs...
Pass 2: Form1.Designer.cs...

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Violation Count: 547
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check the Error and Warnings tabs

Comment: If you use VS2015, set the dropdownlist in the error list to Build + IntelliSense